# Add multiple CollectionViewCell.xib in Collectionview

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, switch-statement

Actually, I wanted to add multiple xib files to a single `UIcollectionview` . I have switch case to assign different `collectionviewcell` for different `indexpath`. I have not got any clear ideas how to make it possible.

```
CollectionCell *cell1;
 switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            [self.Collection registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CCollectionCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"board"];
            cell1 = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"dashboard" forIndexPath:indexPath];
            return cell1;
            break;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You code style doesn't work because `indexPath.row` is not fixed param for the swift, so do code like below :

in `viewDidLoad`

```
 [self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCell0" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell0"];

 [self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCell1" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell1"];
// do same for all your six xib
```

in `numberofItems`

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 6;
}
```

in `cellForItem`

```
if(indexpath.row == 0){
   CustomCell0 *cell0 = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell0" forIndexPath:indexPath];

       return cell0;
    }
else if(indexpath.row == 1){
    CustomCell1 *cell1 = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell1" forIndexPath:indexPath];

       return cell1;
    }

    :
    :

else if(indexpath.row == 4){
    CustomCell4 *cell4 = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell4" forIndexPath:indexPath];

      return cell4;
    }
else
    {
    CustomCell5 *cell5 = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell5" forIndexPath:indexPath];

       return cell5;
    }
```

Comment: I just gave an example for  0th indexpath.row. I have give cases till which i have needed

Comment: I want the code to be given in '// your cell for row 0
 '

Comment: Tell me your condition like how much xib you have and in which order you wanted to show them and which xib shows how many times?

Comment: I have totally 6 xib, In each indexpath I have to give this xib's. So i have 6 cases totally in swithcase and when i give the code to add collectionviewcells my code crashes

Answer (score 0):

You still need switch-case or if-else to specify which cell you want to load but these are some change that you can update to make you code shorter.

1. Move registers to `viewDidLoad`, you only need to call it one time:

`-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [collection registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CCollectionCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"board"];
}`

2. `break` will never be called so you can remove it too.

Comment: I have more that 1 collectionviewcell.xib  then should i write the above code for all the xib files?

Comment: Yes, you have to register for all nib that your collection view will use and only register 1 time for each xib file